# React-map-gl geocoder marker showing else where on the webpage than the map

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I'm currently working on this application for school assignment that uses react-map-gl to achieve our map feature. I tried to create a text entry box for location information as the example here : https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/tree/7.0-release/examples/geocoder/src. However, the marker and the text entry box appeared below the map instead of over it and the marker is floating all over the screen when I zoom in and out. I don't see other people to have the same problem or solutions to it here so please help me out

**homepage.js**

```
<div id = "map">
      <Map
      initialViewState={{
        latitude: 47.662777,
        longitude: -122.313877,
        zoom: 14
      }}
      style={{height: 600}}
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/fuwak0o0/cl2vqyhwn000n14tgci6txwby"
      mapboxAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      >
        <GeocoderControl mapboxAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN} position="top-left" />
      </Map>
    </div>
```

**GeocoderControl code (I basically copied and pasted the example)**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useControl, Marker } from 'react-map-gl';
import MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';
/* eslint-disable complexity,max-statements */
export default function GeocoderControl(props) {
    const [marker, setMarker] = useState(null);
    const geocoder = useControl(() => {
        const ctrl = new MapboxGeocoder(Object.assign(Object.assign({}, props), { marker: false, accessToken: props.mapboxAccessToken }));
        ctrl.on('loading', props.onLoading);
        ctrl.on('results', props.onResults);
        ctrl.on('result', evt => {
            var _a;
            props.onResult(evt);
            const { result } = evt;
            const location = result &&
                (result.center || (((_a = result.geometry) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.type) === 'Point' && result.geometry.coordinates));
            if (location && props.marker) {
                setMarker(React.createElement(Marker, Object.assign({}, props.marker, { longitude: location[0], latitude: location[1] })));
            }
            else {
                setMarker(null);
            }
        });
        ctrl.on('error', props.onError);
        return ctrl;
    }, {
        position: props.position
    });
    // @ts-ignore (TS2339) private member
    if (geocoder._map) {
        if (geocoder.getProximity() !== props.proximity && props.proximity !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setProximity(props.proximity);
        }
        if (geocoder.getRenderFunction() !== props.render && props.render !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setRenderFunction(props.render);
        }
        if (geocoder.getLanguage() !== props.language && props.language !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setLanguage(props.language);
        }
        if (geocoder.getZoom() !== props.zoom && props.zoom !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setZoom(props.zoom);
        }
        if (geocoder.getFlyTo() !== props.flyTo && props.flyTo !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setFlyTo(props.flyTo);
        }
        if (geocoder.getPlaceholder() !== props.placeholder && props.placeholder !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setPlaceholder(props.placeholder);
        }
        if (geocoder.getCountries() !== props.countries && props.countries !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setCountries(props.countries);
        }
        if (geocoder.getTypes() !== props.types && props.types !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setTypes(props.types);
        }
        if (geocoder.getMinLength() !== props.minLength && props.minLength !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setMinLength(props.minLength);
        }
        if (geocoder.getLimit() !== props.limit && props.limit !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setLimit(props.limit);
        }
        if (geocoder.getFilter() !== props.filter && props.filter !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setFilter(props.filter);
        }
        if (geocoder.getOrigin() !== props.origin && props.origin !== undefined) {
            geocoder.setOrigin(props.origin);
        }
    }
    return marker;
}
const noop = () => { };
GeocoderControl.defaultProps = {
    marker: true,
    onLoading: noop,
    onResults: noop,
    onResult: noop,
    onError: noop
};
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).